# tkinter: tag_bind in for-loop only passes the last tag as a parameter in the lambda event function

Tags: python, tkinter, tags, bind

I've been struggling with this portion of my code for the past few hours, so I decided to ask on stackoverflow.

First off, here's my code:

```
def place_checkers_init(self):  
    for i,player_piece in enumerate(self.player_pieces):
        tag = "p"+str(i)
        square = self.frame.grid_slaves(player_piece.row, player_piece.col)[0]
        piece = square.create_oval(10,10,90,90,fill=player_piece.color)
        square.itemconfig(piece, tags = tag)
        print(square.gettags(piece))
        square.tag_bind(tag, '<1>', lambda event: self.player_move(tag))
```

To briefly explain the background, self.player_pieces is a list of CheckerPiece objects, which only serves to store information about row, column, color, etc. of a checker piece. Self.frame is a Frame object containing 36 Canvas objects stored as grid. What I'm trying to do on this block of code here is to create checker pieces (ovals) on these individual canvases (checkerboard tiles) using the row and column information stored in CheckerPiece object and bind each of these pieces to Button and execute the class method self.player_move.

So here's my problem: even though I assigned each of these checker pieces their own tags, for some reason all pieces end up with the tag of the last piece in the for loop. That is, when I try printing (on the terminal) the row and column of a checker piece I click on (in my gui) using this definition of self.player_move:

```
def player_move(self, tag):
    index = int(tag[1])
    print(self.player_pieces[index].row, self.player_pieces[index].col)
```

it only prints (4,5) no matter which piece I click, which is the last checker piece that was in the list self.player_pieces.

My guess is that something went wrong in the last parameter of my tag_bind (the lambda function), but I just don't know what to do anymore.

Could I get some help? Thank you!

Comment: Similar questions related to lambda and loops have been asked and answered dozens if not hundreds of times on this site. This is an extremely common problem with a simple solution. Have you done any research before asking?

Comment: @BryanOakley I have looked at all of the posts containing tag_binds and loops and tried editing my code according to the solutions but my tag_bind line still keeps passing in only the last tag into the function. It seems like the event that's getting passed in is pointing to the right piece so I'm just confused why the tag isn't pointing to the right piece either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal formulation of your question can be written as:

```
for f in [lambda: print(n, end=' ') for n in range(5)]:
    f()
```

Output:

```
4 4 4 4 4 # why do the lambdas only print the last value of 'n' ?
```

Now replace by:

```
for f in [lambda n=n: print(n, end=' ') for n in range(5)]:
    f()
```

Output

```
0 1 2 3 4 # yeah!
```

Comment: Ahhhh, yes I realized what I forgot. Thank you!